# Using php check if the value of a field is a mysql function or not

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a custom MVC framework in that I have a function which takes in array and triggers insert queries.

```
function insertFromArray($array, $table) {

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $fields[] = "`" . $key . "`";
        $values[] = "'" . $value . "'";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (" . implode(",", $fields) . ") VALUES (" . implode(",", $values) . ")";

    mysql_query($sql);
    return (mysql_error()) ? mysql_error() : mysql_insert_id();
}
```

But when I get some mysql function instead of a string or integer my function does not work say for a filed name 'dateTime' I get value = NOW() in that case my query would be

```
INSERT INTO `$table` (`field1`, `field2`, `dateTime`) VALUES ('value1','value2','NOW()')
```

And this would throw error I want some generic solution so that my queries would run in either case if it is a string, number or if it is any mysql function.

I tried creating an array of all the functions and started with comparisons like if the starting of the $value matches any function from the array of mysql functions but I do not think that is a good way to do it, is there any better way to do that

Comment: please! Stop using deprecated mysql_* functions! They are deprecated and removed in next php release. Use mysqli_* or better use PDO

Comment: There should be a way to know that they are SQL functions rather than a regular value. Ex: a dropdown beside the textbox that describes what type of input you are expecting. In case of SQL functions, maybe try wrapping them in metadata string, ex: [SQL_FUNCTION=NOW()] whatever, and parse it before creating the insert query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array to store your SQL keywords/function names. Then in your query string, you test to see if the current value is an SQL word or not. If it is, don't quote it, otherwise, you quote it.

Here is an example:

```
function is_sql_term($term)
{
   $sql_terms = array('NOW()', 'DATE()', ...);
   return in_array($term, $sql_terms) || preg_match("/\(.*\)/", $term);
}
```

Then you test as follows:

```
$values[] = is_sql_term($value) ? $value : "'" . $value . "'";
```

Comment: Well I actually tried something similar but this logic fails when there are parameters to be passed in those functions so in that case I started checking if starting of my script matches with any of the sql function say there is a function DAYOFMONTH('2001-11-00') so I started matching if my value starts with something like "DAYOFMONTH(" but I am not convinces with this approach

Comment: "when there are parameters to be passed in those functions", you could simply use a regular expression to test.

Comment: Updated my answer with regular expression included

Answer (score 1):

```
$values[] = "'" . $value . "'";
```

The above line treats all values as strings and this causes the issue. Do not treat all values as strings and enclose them by single quotes.

You could even make the value part an array itself with 2 elements: one for the value and one for the type of the value (string, numeric, function, etc.) and would treat ech of them differently while creating the insert statement.

And pls use mysql or PDO instead of php's old mysql extension.